# I cannot control my fetch robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all. I am trying to move a fetch robot go straigh. For example my robot spawn in position (0,0). it cannot go straight to (-3,0) or (-3, -3). i see the code here: https://github.com/fetchrobotics/fetch_gazebo/blob/gazebo2/fetch_gazebo_demo/scripts/demo.py
I don't understand this code:

---

```
    move_goal = MoveBaseGoal()
    move_goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = x
    move_goal.target_pose.pose.position.y = y
    move_goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.z = sin(theta/2.0)
    move_goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = cos(theta/2.0)
    move_goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = frame
    move_goal.target_pose.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
```

can anyone explain to me please?
sorry my english is not good. thanks all!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276506/i-cannot-control-my-fetch-robot/) by [dong_96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32729/dong_96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend you to have a look at [ROS Actions](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib).

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0